# XCode 7 and Swift confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

Quite confused:
I recently installed `Xcode 7` because I was told that it was a prerequisite to learn `Objective-C`. So I went online, found an `Objective-C` tutorial and tried playing around with commands such as `NSLog` and `NSString` in `Xcode Playground`, but `Xcode` does not want to cooperate with me on that.

After some googling I discovered that there is something called `Swift` and it is linked to `Xcode`. So, question is: Is `Xcode 7` only working with `Swift`? Or can I configure `Xcode` so that I can use `Objective-C` code in it?

Is there a difference between using a Playground or not, in relation to `Swift` vs `Objective-C`?

Comment: when you're creating a new project or new class, there's an option whether to use Objective-C or Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode Playgrounds work only with Swift language. But there is an excellent 3rd-party playground for Objective-C: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/KZPlayground

Answer (score 2):

You can make an application with either/both Objective-C and Swift languages in an Xcode project.

On the other hand, Playgrounds only work with Swift.